# How to analyse streaming data from Google Analytics 4 to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-analytics, streaming

I have streaming export of GA4 data to BigQuery. I want to analyse data as soon as it arrives in _intraday table in order to personalize experience in next step

I created users' profiles from GA data and I have '3 last products viewed' column but its from data from last day. I want to update this column as soon as I can from _intraday table
I don't know how to approach this problem.

I tried to setup cloud function with trigger from cloud logging but streaming data in BigQuery doesn't log inserts of streaming data

Answer (score 0):

Within each dataset, a table is imported for each day of export. Daily tables have the format “ga_sessions_YYYYMMDD”. Intraday data is imported approximately three times a day. Intraday tables have the format “ga_sessions_intraday_YYYYMMDD”. During the same day, each import of intraday data overwrites the previous import in the same table. When the daily import is complete, the intraday table from the previous day is deleted. **For the current day, until the first intraday import, there is no intraday table.** If an intraday-table write fails, then the previous day’s intraday table is preserved. Data for the current day is not final until the daily import is complete. You may notice differences between intraday and daily data based on active user sessions that cross the time boundary of last intraday import.

Source: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089&ref=ga4bigquery.com

```
select
_table_suffix as table_suffix,
count(distinct 
concat(fullvisitorid, 
cast(visitstarttime as string))) 
as sessions
from
  `bigquery-public- data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_intraday_20160801`
where
  totals.visits = 1
group by
  table_suffix
```

Comment: Hi, it's not what I'm looking for. 
Example: user clicked something on my site,from google analytics event is sent to bigquery and as soon as this event is in BigQuery I want to add this data to user profile 
I don't want to be consistent. I want to be near real time. After 3 events and based on that last 3 events I want to recommend something